# How to decompress gzip http response in wso2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, gzip, wso2-esb

I have a base service which returns gzipped response which wso2 esb is unable to understand. So when i create a pass through proxy of the above web service and when i try to run the service in soapUI, the result that esb shows me is the wsdl file of the above service. I am unable to find out how to decompress the response sent from the base service in wso2 esb. is there any way to do it? Looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the http response gzipped or the message that gets returned by the response (i.e. the http services returnes a gzipped xml)?

Comment: the http services returnes a gzipped xml

Comment: This is a bad practice as the HTTP protocol supports gzip out of the box without the need to gzip the content send within the message. If you can corrent the service to send unzipped xml and make it use gzip on a transport level it will be better. If you don't controll it you should implement custom esb transformer/adapter that will unzip the message (unfortunatelly I can't help with that).

Comment: Ya got your point. Thanks for the help:)